# Getting the latest record by DATETIME or NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.id, creator, ls.name, ld.timestampOut
FROM 
    countermeasures c
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    lifecycleDetails ld ON ld.documentId = c.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    lifecycleState ls ON ls.id = ld.lifecycleStatus
WHERE 
    ld.timestampOut = (SELECT MAX(timestampOut) from lifecycleDetails)
    OR ld.timestampOut IS NULL
```

I'm getting the following results:

[image]

I know I'm doing this wrong, but what I'm wanting is the record with the latest date. If timestampOut is null then I'm wanting that record instead. In the end I'm only wanting 1 records not 2.

Thanks!

Comment: which rdbms - sql server, oracle, mysql, postgres ?

Comment: You need a case statement. On mobile or I'd post an example.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: add `limit 1` at the very end?

Comment: @user3058333 that will not always give the `NULL` record first.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT id, creator, name, timestampOut
FROM (SELECT c.id, creator, ls.name, ld.timestampOut,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by (case when ld.timestampOut is null then 1 else 2 end),
                                                         timestampOut desc
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM countermeasures c
      LEFT OUTER JOIN lifecycleDetails ld ON ld.documentId = c.id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN lifecycleState ls ON ls.id = ld.lifecycleStatus
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked perfectly! I will need to do a bit of research on this to figure out exactly how it worked. I've never used row_number() over partition before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT top 1 
c.id, creator, ls.name, ld.timestampOut

...

WHERE 
ld.timestampOut = (SELECT MAX(timestampOut) from lifecycleDetails)
OR ld.timestampOut IS NULL

ORDER BY timestampOut
```